# Python pip is messed up- How to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, anaconda

I recently installed anaconda and apparently it messed up my pip. when I install a package with it like `pip install virtualenv` it says:

```
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (20.24.3)
```

But when I want to use it with `virtualenv venv`, it says:

```
Command 'virtualenv' not found.
```

And when I do `python -m site` It shows:

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/user/.local',
    '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python311.zip',
    '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11',
    '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
    '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/user/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Whereas my pip is in `~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages`! So apparently pip packages are no more visible to my python.

What is the problem? How to fix this?

Comment: `pip` is not messed up.  Remember that most `pip` packages do not install command-line commands.  It's just that the `virtualenv` command must not be in your path.  Do `locate virtualenv` to see where it was placed.  You can make a symbolic link from `~/bin/virtualenv` to there.

Comment: Makes sense. `pip` can't install scripts to the usual system bin directories without sudo access (which you should _never_ use with pip). You can try using `pip install --user virtualenv` so that scripts can be installed to `~/.local/bin`

Comment: I guessed pip is messed up because for instance when I do `pip install torch` it says it is installed. But when importing in python, it says not found. So regardless of this specific issue, I think pip packages may not be visible to my conda python...

Comment: FYI, I just did `pip install --user virtualenv` and still it says `Command 'virtualenv' not found.`

Comment: Updated the question. Look at my `python -m` output

Answer (score 1):

```
python3 -m venv env
```

```
source env/bin/activate
```

[READ IN packaging.python.org](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

Comment: I guess I made progress. But now when I want to install `requirements.txt`, it shows error. Is there an way to specify a specific python version with this? Right now this is the error:
        `note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
      Failed to build numpy
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]
...
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.`

Comment: It means Numpy failed to build, but the error information seems incomplete. Did you google the error message?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).